# Javascript toggle hide/unhide (need to use code more than once but not working)

Tags: javascript, toggle

I need help changing this javascript code so I can use it multiple times on one page. It works once but second one opens first unhide. I am only able to use javascript for this.

```html
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display == 'none')
e.style.display = 'block';
else
e.style.display = 'none';
}
//-->
</script>
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');"><b><span style="color: #0085cc;">TITLE GOES HERE<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" style="font-size:0.7em;"></i></span></b></a><div id="foo" style=display:none;>- Example<br>
- Example<br>
- Example<br>
- Example<br>
<a href="http://www.example.com/"><b><span style="color: #0085cc;">More</span></a></b></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is setting correct id values for `toggle_visibility()`, say:

```
toggle_visibility('foo'); // Will toggle #foo element
toggle_visibility('bar'); // Will toggle #bar element
```

If you have several  elements with `toggle_visibility('foo')`, they all will hide/unhide #foo element.

Answer (score 0):

Try $.toggle

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```html
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
$("#"+id).toggle(100);
}
//-->
</script>
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');"><b><span style="color: #0085cc;">TITLE GOES HERE<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" style="font-size:0.7em;"></i></span></b></a><div id="foo" style=display:none;>- Example<br>
- Example<br>
- Example<br>
- Example<br>
<a href="http://www.example.com/"><b><span style="color: #0085cc;">More</span></a></b></div>
</body>
</html>
```